# Google Could Platform using app engine(node.js) ,connect to clould SQL

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I was develop my web server on my own computer, I am trying to put it on Google Could Platform, I using mysql for data storage.

The database putting on the Cloud sql is fine, but if my application using app engine to run it, it seem cannot connect to the cloud sql, because I am using different library with the google document.

this is the code How the sample connect to the database:

```
const Knex = require('knex');
function connect () {
  const config = {
    user: process.env.SQL_USER,
    password: process.env.SQL_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.SQL_DATABASE
  };

  if (process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    config.socketPath = `/cloudsql/${process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}`;
  }

  // Connect to the database
  const knex = Knex({
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: config
  });

  return knex;
}
```

this is the code How I connect to the database:

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');
 function connect () {

       var mysql = require('mysql');
       var con = mysql.createPool({
                host: "HostIPAddress",
                user: "MyUserName",
                password: "MyPassword",
                database: "MyDB"
            });    
       return con;
}
```

However, all my code is done I cannot change my library to do that, I was try to using **Authorized networks** to add my app to the white list, but app engine did not have a static IP address.
any idea what should I do?

Comment: Knex uses the mysql library under the covers so you should not have any issues using the same properties directly. Have you tried using the same socketPath value as in the example?

Comment: ok, I put my application to the computer engine, it work fine ,thanks for your help